# wifi-menu isn't connecting to the internet and giving errors

Tags: networking, wifi, networkmanager

Previously, my wifi-menu has been working fine and I could connect on my home network, but I noticed my GUI Network Manager wasn't working, so I used these commands.

```
systemctl enable NetworkManager.service
systemctl start NetworkManager.service
```

And networks popped up on my GUI, but now I can't connect to any of the displayed networks. After running:

```
sudo wifi-menu
```

It now gives me the output of:

```
Scanning for networks... n180211: Could not set interface 'p2p-dev-wlp1s0' UP
p2p-dev-wlp1s0: Failed to initialize driver interface
```

Now I cannot connect to the internet. I tried restarting systemctl, but that didn't work either.

Comment: what is the output of `dmesg | tail` after `systemctl start NetworkManager.service` and what is `systemctl status NetworkManager.service` telling you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use (or *used*) `wifi-menu` you are apparently using Arch Linux, or a derivative thereof.
Here is what the Arch Wiki says about wireless configuration (my emphasis):

> There are many solutions to choose from, but remember that all of them
>   are **mutually exclusive**; you should not run two daemons simultaneously.

And this about NetworkManager:

> You must ensure that no other service that wants to configure the
>   network is running; in fact, multiple networking services will
>   conflict.

In other words, in order for one to work - you need to **disable** the other. In this case, if you want to use NetworkManager, you need to disable `netctl` (and vice versa).

Read more **[here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#Wireless_management)** and **[here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Installation)**.